# Why does grouping the output of a Powershell pipe sometimes not work?

Tags: powershell

I have read that when the output of [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) (with `-GroupBy`) is not
grouped, you need to 1. sort and 2. pass `-AutoSize`. Sometimes this does not
seem to work. This is te test case I came up with:

```
PS C:\> ls -Path C:\Windows\help -Include "*.chm" -Recurse|sort Directory|ft -GroupBy Directory -Auto

    Directory: C:\Windows\help

Mode         LastWriteTime Length Name
----         ------------- ------ ----
-a--- 23.05.2011     10:54  21544 NVWCPFI.chm

    Directory: C:\Windows\help

Mode         LastWriteTime Length Name
----         ------------- ------ ----
-a--- 23.05.2011     10:54  21879 NVWCPESM.chm

...
```

Why is the output not grouped by directory? Why are there two separate entries
for the same directory? How can I group the output? (Please ignore the fact,
that output of the first command is already grouped, I just use this command as
a test case.)

**Edit**

As pointed out I initially forgot the the `Directory` argument to sort. (The output still has the same problem.)

I am using Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 1):

In order to group output in `Format-Table` it first needs to be sorted. A technet blog, which has a discussion on this, is [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/14/use-powershell-to-group-and-format-output.aspx). While you do have a Sort-Object cmdlet you dont choose a value to sort on. *Note* I do not get the same output at you with your cmdlet on powershell 3.0

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\help -Include "*.chm" -Recurse| Sort-Object Directory | Format-Table -GroupBy Directory
```

The output will indeed be sorted but i gather this is not what you are looking for. Another approach that might be more desired would be to use `Select-Object` to only output the desired information.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\help -Include "*.chm" -Recurse| Sort-Object Directory | Select Name,Directory | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You would need to experiment with the values of `Select-Object` to get your desired output. The next example would give you count information of chm's in folders. Not `Format-Table` related at all but interesting none the less.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\help -Include "*.chm" -Recurse | Group-Object Directory
```

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed forget the directory argument, it did not solve my problem unfortunately. I tried your suggestions without success, I begin to think that this is related to Powershell 2.0.

Comment: Will test with 2.0 and see what i can get.

Comment: I just tested with 2.0 and i can recreate your example. However using `Select Name,Directory` does help create a proper output although putting it into a table does not change it appearance. Please show desired output if this is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your continued effort. Do you happen to know how we could continue this conversation in a chat? In the meantime please see http://pastebin.com/kr6Wkr56.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if work:

```
...|sort directory |ft -GroupBy...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @skolima: no, this is an answer..adding property Directory to sort-object and it work

Comment: I Skolima was trying to say that you are not explaining why this is an answer. One of the OP's questions was _Why is the output not grouped by directory?_. I think you just need to update your answer to be more explanatory.